# What is necessary for a magician to be able to cast spells in space?

Tags: spells, optimization, magic, shadowrun-sr3

<sup>[Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/how-can-i-send-magicians-into-space) but wrong edition.</sup>

It is supposed to be impossible to use magic in space. In-universe reports of sub-orbital flights where magicians attempted to do so ended up in death or madness. Also astral projections up outside the atmosphere usually end up with one more corpse on the ground.

What is the bare minimum for a prime runner magician to be able to function in space? Besides what is required for a normal human to be able to *not die* in space (space suit, radiation, etc). The mundane aspects are of no interest.

Answer (score 7):

Space is considered a mana warp. The higher you go, the bigger the background count.

From Magic in the Shadows:

> At 71km of altitude, background count is 1. From there, each km increases the count by 1, until it is 10 for heights of 80km and above.

The lv 10 mana warp stats:

- Magic Reduction -12
- Warp Damage 14D
- Magical TN modifier +10
- Drain TN modifier +5 power, +3 levels

Therefore, the magician will need to heed the following:

- Magic rating 13 (through initiation). If he can't be left with at least 1 magic rating point, his foci won't work.
- Leave all your spirits at home. They would go Poof the same turn they appear. Don't bother conjuring up there. And if you end up conjuring something, I'd dread what it would be.
- **NEVER** astrally perceive or project. Going astral means dealing with 14D physical warp damage each turn.
- All TN will increase by +10. The centering metamagic ability might help with this, but don't bet on it. I'd rather suggest you leave centering to be used on the drain and let the RNJesus smile on your d6's to explode.
- Cast only low-force spells. First, your lowered magic rating means you will take physical drain if you cast a normal-force spell (as you are used to back in the ground). Also helps with the drain, see below:
- Take care of your drain. Even a 2L drain will become 7D.
- <s>Learn the ancient talent of [spell matrix](http://earthdawn.wikia.com/wiki/Spells)...</s> Scratch that. I don't want to be shot by Mulvihill again. It is a *completely different* thing called filtering metamagic (SOTA 2063), that can give you a respite against the warp. For a very limited time.

If the GM is willing, some stations might have a slightly lower warp (1 or 2 points) because of the people and the plants aboard. But this means going into the Z-O or Daedalus. You can bet your momma's gammaware simrig that they stationed their best initiate to provide magic security there.

*Runners don't go into Z-O*. Period.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that a little bit further along in the timeline, Ares has a portion of Daedalus specifically built with plants and other life forms to create a stable manasphere that Firewatch teams can use to go to the metaplanes to hunt bug queens. Of course... it's also designed to be violently and rapidly ejected out into space, so that any bugs that may follow the team back die a quick and horrible death (the team too, but the families get the hazard pay).

Comment: @T.J.L. but then it is an entirely different set of rules. After leaving the hands of FASA, it is heartwarming the game survived in spirit, but only in spirit. Also, I strongly object these SR+ED crossover things (and bringing this up at a convention was what caused Mike Mulvilhil to "shoot" me).